# Hiding an element with javascript on mouse click and showing on second click

Tags: javascript, class

CSS:

```
ol{display: block;} // display: ""; throws an error in the console(FF)
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript">!js is here!</script>
<body>
<h2>Title</h2>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="expand" />
<ol>
    <li>Value 1</li>
    <li>Value 1</li>
    <li>Value 1</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript: // trying to just hide the element for now

```
window.onload = function() {
    function expand() {
        var ol = document.getElementByTagName('ol');
        ol.style.display('none');
    }
    function init() {
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
        btn.addEventListener('click', expand, false);
    }
}
```

I've been searching high and low for something similar, everything I found used an additional library(utility.js, jquery etc.), but for learning purposes I want to do this in pure JS.

Every source online cites `element.className = "newClass";`. I tried that by making a class `.hide{display: none;}` and `.show{display: "";}`, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Then I switched to manipulating the style (`element.style.display("none");`), but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ol.style.display = "none"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your JavaScript appears before the elements are loaded into the DOM, you need to wait until the window has loaded (or document is ready, not shown in this snippet) before adding the event listeners to the button.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var style = document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0].style;
    style.display = (style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
  }, true);
}, true);
```

To toggle display, you can use the `display` CSS attribute set to either `block` for displayed as a block element, or `none` for not displayed at all.

Comment: To see this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/steveukx/yQQ4v/ it's worth noting that my example also assumes the availability of addEventListener, to cater for versions of IE that use attachEvent instead check out http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Answer (score 3):

Well you would want to use getElementsByTagName instead of getElementByTagName, note its plural. This will then return an array.

```
var arrayOfElements = document.getElementsByTagName('ol');
var aSingleElement = document.getElementsByTagName('ol')[0];

aSingleElement .style.display('none');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    function expand() {
        var ol = document.getElementsByTagName('ol');
        ol[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
    function init() {
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
        btn.addEventListener('click', expand, false);
    }
    init();
}​
```

First:
`element.style.display("none")` should be `element.style.display = "none"`

Second:

`var ol = document.getElementByTagName('ol');` should be `var ol = document.getElementByTagName('ol')`;
plus it returns an array of objects and you must access your OL like this: `ol[0].style.display = 'none';` (assuming it is an only OL on your page)

Also:

```
ol{display: block;} // display: ""; throws an error in the console(FF)
```

error is thrown because "" is not an allowed value for display. But you may set `element.style.display = "";`

Comment: Gave me an error "TypeError: ol[0].style.display is not a function @ /expand.html:10"

Comment: see this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9A2Q7/. It works fine there. Are you sure you are have `ol[0].style.display = "none"` and not `ol[0].style.display("none")`? Error sounds like you have `ol[0].style.display("none")` which is incorrect